# Dynamics Crm: Get metadata for statuscode/statecode mapping

Tags: c#, metadata, dynamics-crm-2011

In Dynamics CRM 2011, on the Incident entity, the "Status Reason" optionset (aka statuscode) is related to the "Status" optionset (aka statecode)

e.g. see this screenshot

[image: screenshot of CRM field options]

When I use the API to retrieve the Status Reason optionset, like so:

```
        RetrieveAttributeRequest attributeRequest = new RetrieveAttributeRequest
        {
            EntityLogicalName = "incident",
            LogicalName = "statuscode",
            RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
        };
        RetrieveAttributeResponse attributeResponse = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)serv.Execute(attributeRequest);
        AttributeMetadata attrMetadata = (AttributeMetadata)attributeResponse.AttributeMetadata;
        StatusAttributeMetadata statusMetadata = (StatusAttributeMetadata)attrMetadata;
        var dict = new Dictionary<int?, string>();
        foreach (OptionMetadata optionMeta in statusMetadata.OptionSet.Options)
        {
            dict.Add(optionMeta.Value, optionMeta.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label);
        }
```

It works in that I get the whole list of "Status Reason" (statuscode) options. However, I dont get any info about which "Status Reason" (statuscode) options relate to which "Status" (statecode) options.

How do I get that information?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You already have everything try insert this code inside of foreach:

```cs
 int stateOptionValue = (int)((StatusOptionMetadata)optionMeta).State;
```

See [StatusAttributeMetaData.OptionSet.Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.optionmetadata.aspx) hierarchy can return a type called [StatusOptionMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.statusoptionmetadata_members.aspx) if you use the State property of the StatusOptionMetadata, it will return the statecode this statuscode belongs to.

Comment: Ah, ok, so I should use StatusOptionMetadata in the foreach instead of OptionMetadata - will try it out ...

Answer (score 8):

Here is how you can get it by querying the database

```
SELECT distinct e.LogicalName as entity,
      smState.Value AS stateCode,
      smstate.AttributeValue,
      smStatus.Value AS [statuscode/statusreason],
      smStatus.AttributeValue
FROM StatusMap sm
     JOIN Entity e ON sm.ObjectTypeCode = e.ObjectTypeCode
     JOIN StringMap smState ON smState.AttributeValue = sm.State
                           AND smState.ObjectTypeCode = e.ObjectTypeCode
                           AND smState.AttributeName = 'StateCode'
     JOIN StringMap smStatus ON smStatus.AttributeValue = sm.Status
                            AND smStatus.ObjectTypeCode = e.ObjectTypeCode
                            AND smStatus.AttributeName = 'StatusCode'
WHERE  e.LogicalName in ('lead')
ORDER BY e.LogicalName,
      smState.AttributeValue,
      smStatus.AttributeValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code that will output State/Status mapping for a given entity (you just need to provide the orgServiceProxy):

```
    var dictState = new Dictionary<int, OptionMetadata>();
    var dictStatus = new Dictionary<int, List<OptionMetadata>>();

    string entityName = "lead";
    int count=0;
    using (var orgServiceProxy = GetOrgServiceProxy(orgServiceUriOnLine))
    {
        RetrieveAttributeResponse attributeResponse = GetAttributeData(orgServiceProxy, entityName, "statecode");
        AttributeMetadata attrMetadata = (AttributeMetadata)attributeResponse.AttributeMetadata;
        StateAttributeMetadata stateMetadata = (StateAttributeMetadata)attrMetadata;
        foreach (OptionMetadata optionMeta in stateMetadata.OptionSet.Options)
        {
            dictState.Add(optionMeta.Value.Value,optionMeta);
            dictStatus.Add(optionMeta.Value.Value,new List<OptionMetadata>());
        }

        attributeResponse = GetAttributeData(orgServiceProxy, entityName, "statuscode");
        attrMetadata = (AttributeMetadata)attributeResponse.AttributeMetadata;
        StatusAttributeMetadata statusMetadata = (StatusAttributeMetadata)attrMetadata;

        foreach (OptionMetadata optionMeta in statusMetadata.OptionSet.Options)
        {
            int stateOptionValue = ((StatusOptionMetadata)optionMeta).State.Value;
            var statusList = dictStatus[stateOptionValue];
            statusList.Add(optionMeta);
            count++;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Number of mappings: {count}");
    foreach (var stateKvp in dictState.OrderBy(x=> x.Key))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"State: {stateKvp.Value.Value}: {stateKvp.Value.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label}");
        var statusList = dictStatus[stateKvp.Key];
        Console.WriteLine($"\tStatuses");
        foreach (var status in statusList.OrderBy(s => s.Value))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{stateKvp.Value.Value}: {status.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label}");
        }
    }
```